# Transmitter & receiver circuit for high voltage lights

Tags: rf, light, transmitter, receiver

I want to control my room's lights by wireless circuit - like RF or whatever.

In my country, the lamps and lights work on 220V AC.

I'm still beginner, I have done this before and it worked, but by infrared circuit and it wasn't effective enough.

Can you introduce me to any useful tutorial or circuits like RF, etc.

I just want to build an effective circuit to turn lights on and off, not control the brightness.

Please, no infrared.

Comment: What's wrong with infrared?  Too short range? Doesn't go through walls? You have to aim the transmitter at the receiver?  Doesn't work in bright sunlight?

Comment: There are tons of WiFi switches available on the market. Are you trying to design something for you own education?

Comment: Yes. exactly , like this problems you said , it's too weak to work easily from long distance or aim the transmitter at the receiver. indirectly. and it takes a lot of effort to wrok corrcetly .

Comment: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to transmit this data, a cheap and effective way would be one of those 433MHz transmitter/receiver modules which have decent range and are definitely suited for this.